# Why can "be" connect "keep"?

Tags: grammar

> All I have to do **is keep** Talyor in bulky sweaters for a few years.

I always think "be" should connect "to do" or "doing". Such as you can only say `I'm eating.` But you can't say `I'm eat.`

And I find another example, `is keeping`

> His business **is keeping** him busy.

Comment: I am sorry, but i am not clear on what the nature of your concern or confusion is.  What do you mean by *"be" should connect "doing"*? What alternate sentance are you comparing your example with? Please expand your question a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [following sentence patterns](https://www.zybang.com/question/4c633e8882950fd3e26b5d9155613f58.html), you can omit the "to" before a verb.

> All I have to do is (to ) take a good rest.
>
> All I can do is (to)wait.
>
> What you should do is simply (to) apologize to him.
>
> All I did yesterday was (to) eat and sleep.
>
> All I have to do is learn English.

Here are more discussions about ["have to do is"](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/all-you-have-to-do-is-studying-study-to-study-hard.1188654/)